# Dynamically Readjustable Arrays and OpenMP

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, openmp, realloc

I have a function that uses realloc to dynamically adjust the memory of a 1D array as the initial size of the array cannot be predetermined .I want to parallelize this code by dividing the task across multiple threads whereby each thread would work on a smaller 1D array that they would dynamically readjust according to the memory required. As part of the process each thread also produces a private variable that would contain the final size of the small array.

In Openmp I want to access the private copy of these arrays (through the master thread) and put all the small arrays together to obtain a final array based on the size of the arrays computed by each thread.

Is it possible ??

Comment: put differently: why would it be impossible?

Comment: Are you expecting a Yes/No answer?

Comment: I have tried my best to do it but somehow it does not work out. I am not asking a yes or no answer. I am asking what pragmas should be used to make it work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and how it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with a dynamic array such as `std::vector`. For example let's assume that you have an array called `data` with values between zero and one and `n` elements and you want to select out values greater that 0.5 and store them in a new array `vec`. You could do exactly what you want like this

```
double data[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) data[i] = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;

std::vector<double> vec;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    std::vector<double> vec_private;
    #pragma omp for nowait 
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(data[i]>0.5) vec_private.push_back(data[i]);
    }
    #pragma omp critcal
    vec.insert(vec.end(), vec_private.begin(), vec_private.end());
}
```

To do this without a critical section requires a bit more work. It requires saving an array of the size for each array and them doing a cumulative sum (aka prefix sum) on that array in a single section. Once we have the cumulative sum we can use it to merge the arrays in parallel.

```
int *sizea;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    #pragma omp single
    {   
        sizea = new int [nthreads+1];
        sizea[0] = 0;
    }
    std::vector<double> vec_private;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(data[i]>0.5) vec_private.push_back(data[i]);
    }
    sizea[omp_get_thread_num()+1] = vec_private.size();
    #pragma omp barrier
    #pragma omp single
    {
        int size = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<nthreads+1; i++) {
            size += sizea[i];
            sizea[i] = size;            
        }
        vec.resize(size);
    }
    std::copy(vec_private.begin(), vec_private.end(), vec.begin()+sizea[omp_get_thread_num()]);
}
delete[] sizea;
```